# Regex - "['!@#$%*][()=_+{}:\";?,.\/A-Za-z0-9\s-]" is allowing < and > characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Below RegEx is allowing < >

```
functionA = function () 
{ 
    var value = "sdfhf$#%##<>*"; 
    var val = new RegExp("['!@#$%*\]\[()=_+{}:\";?,.\/\A-Za-z0-9\s-]"); 
    return val.test(value); 
}
```

Comment: Can you give some **expected** vs **actual** results? Hard to see what you're asking, especially when it throws a `ReferenceError`

Comment: you should also clarify what language this is.... i'm guessing JS but you've tagged it as both JS *and* C#

Comment: This should not allow < & > as per given expression.

Comment: This Regex will match a string with only two characters. These characters would have to be present in the regular expression. You would have to change the regular expression to meet your needs. Please update the question to provide the expected result. Also, check using this tool to better understand the regular expression https://regex101.com/

Comment: Regular expression is common for C# and JS.instead of marking negative please share your idea

Comment: You didn't give much information about what you want to achieve using this regex, but if you want your test to return false if one of these characters are present, you should be using this regex instead: `^[^<>]*$`. [Click to see the test](https://regex101.com/r/y2tssz/2).

Comment: Using (<|>)+ as the expression should work. Can you check using the same? The capture group (<|>) matches 1st or the 2nd character, + Quantifier - Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

Answer (score 1):

`val.test(value)` tests whether the regexp matches *anywhere* in the string. It returns `true` because the regexp matches the first character of the string. It doesn't match the `<>` characters, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/uP43Sx/1).

If you want to test the whole string, you need to repeat the regexp and anchor it at both ends:

```js
functionA = function () 
{ 
    var value = "sdfhf$#%##<>*"; 
    var val = /^['!@#$%*\]\[()=_+{}:\";?,.\/\A-Za-z0-9\s-]*$/;
    return val.test(value);
}
console.log(functionA());
```

or you can invert the character set and the sense of the test:

```js
functionA = function () 
{ 
    var value = "sdfhf$#%##<>*"; 
    var val = /[^'!@#$%*\]\[()=_+{}:\";?,.\/\A-Za-z0-9\s-]/;
    return !val.test(value);
}
console.log(functionA());
```

Comment: What are you doing different from the code in my snippets, which clearly works.